# Hosting Vue app with Nginx and Express api on same host. Do I need two SSL certs, how to configure nginx?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have an Ubuntu VPS, and I have dockerized a simple Vue App, which is served by Nginx. I have set up SSL for it.

On same host, I have a container running Nodejs Express, which is routing simple queries to MySql database. Express is listening port 8080.

Everything works invidually - I can access the site with 443, and separately I can access the rest api with http://domain:8080 in Postman.

I have however been stuck with how to get Express to listen for https requests so I can use the rest api within the site.

Do I need another SSL cert for the Express? Or is enough if I bypass some url to the localhost:8080? Obviously I still want the site to be accessible with https://domain

What did I miss? Or did I miss it totally?

What I tried was something like:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass     http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Within both 80 and 443 nginx listeners.

I however always get 502 badateway, if I try to access https://domain/api/foo. I expected it to return response from http://domain:8080/foo.

Comment: Hello, can you please provide your entire nginx conf file ? 
You can also check the logs of nginx, that should be in /var/log/nginx/error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong was that the nginx container passed proxy to localhost, which of course I realized a bit late that was pointing to nginx container localhost, not the actual host.

I rewrote my compose.yml, the containers are now in the same network, which provides access to nodejs container in the nginx conf.

Now it works as expected.